# What can I do to make sure the login screen shows on both my monitor and TV?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, login, display, hdmi

So here is the thing. I have 2 screens connected to my computer. Display mode is "mirror". However when I turn my computer on, the login box is only available on my monitor, not my TV.
So even if I just want to use my TV, I have to turn my monitor on and off again just to be able to log in.
I'd like to have the login screen on both my monitor and TV when I start my computer.
How do I do that ?
Thx !

My version of Ubuntu is 21.10

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting an answer is enough.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Won't happen again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share your current monitor configuration with gdm:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml
```

Comment: Hi Vanadium, thanks for your reply. 
I'm a noob so I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about.. 
I will do some research on the meaning of "gdm" and that command line you shared with me and see if I can figure it out myself.
Wish me luck ! 
Thanks again

Comment: This command copies the user monitor configuration to the configuration of the login screen.

Comment: Thanks vanadium ! It worked !
So much better now...